# What's the correct definition of activity?

Tags: thermodynamics

I learned activity equals 'activity coefficient' times 'mole fraction' but i also learned it equals 'activity coefficient' times 'partial pressure / standard pressure (1bar)'.
But there's something really confusing me that if activity coefficient for mole fraction and 'partial pressure / standard pressure (1bar)' is equal, then mole fraction and 'partial pressure / standard pressure (1bar)' should be the same.
But from the definition of partial pressure, which is 'partial pressure = mole fraction times total pressure', 'mole fraction and 'partial pressure / standard pressure (1bar)' should be the same.' doesn't seem to make sense.
So is the activity coefficient for mole fraction and activity coefficient for 'partial pressure/standard pressure' the same?

Comment: First of all, these are not definitions (where would you derive eg the activity coefficients?). Second, depending of the physical form we may measure concentration for the activity of solutions, partial pressure for gases, etc. So the role/meaning of activity coefficient is the same, but the corresponding activity coefficient would have the corresponding numerical value and unit/dimension.

Answer (score 2):

A good definition [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_coefficient), to quote:

> An activity coefficient is a factor used in thermodynamics to account for deviations from ideal behaviour in a mixture of chemical substances.[1] In an ideal mixture, the microscopic interactions between each pair of chemical species are the same (or macroscopically equivalent, the enthalpy change of solution and volume variation in mixing is zero) and, as a result, properties of the mixtures can be expressed directly in terms of simple concentrations or partial pressures of the substances present e.g. Raoult's law. Deviations from ideality are accommodated by modifying the concentration by an activity coefficient. Analogously, expressions involving gases can be adjusted for non-ideality by scaling partial pressures by a fugacity coefficient.

So, to answer the question: "So is the activity coefficient for mole fraction and activity coefficient for 'partial pressure/standard pressure' the same?", my take on the explanation above is that while one can apply a scale correction factor to partial pressures as opposed to concentration to address deviations from ideal behavior, technically, the latter adjustment factor is referred to as the fugacity coefficient.